# How to turn off sorting in Solr?

Tags: sorting, solr, priority-queue

I have a number of documents stored in Solr cluster, and want to get large amount of them (about 20 millions) by particular query. I use standard approach reading batches of rows (say, 10000) and moving to next batch with `start` parameter. However after about 1 400 000 docs I'm starting to get `OutOfMemoryError`. I believe this is because of the way Solr sorts docs before sending them to the client. As far as I know, it uses priority queue to get only top N results, and thus need not to load headers of *all* documents into memory. However, when I ask it to return results, say, from 1,000,000 to 1,010,000, it has to load headers for all previous 1,000,000 docs too.

I'm looking for a way to avoid this and just **get all results** satisfying query **without sorting**. Is there a way to do it? If not, what is appropriate way to get large number of results from Solr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct. When you search for results from 1,000,000 to 1,010,000, Solr instantiates a priority queue of size 1,010,000.

This is really not a natural use-case for Solr which has been designed to return the top-k list of results, rather than an exhaustive list of results.

You could work around this by filtering by ranges of your primary key (`q=yourquery&fq=ID:[1 TO 1000]&rows=1000`, `q=yourquery&fq=ID:[1001 TO 2000]&rows=1000`, ...) but this is a ugly hack. :-)

Why do you need to get all results? For example, if you need to compute facets or statistics, Solr has two components that can do that efficiently.

Comment: Thanks, it's an option I've missed. Actually, I used Solr mostly not as search engine (with sorting by relevance and all such features) but rather as a storage with capability to tokenize and stem texts easily. Later I decided that MongoDB with Lucene in front-end is more suitable for such purposes. So now I'm just trying to move all the data from Solr to MongoDB and thus really need to get all documents, batch by batch.